# Error API REST Slim

Tags: rest, doctrine, slim

> Slim Application Error Type:
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException

Tengo una API REST configurada con Slim y Doctrine y necesito resolver este error. El error aparece cuando realizo una petición HTTP desde mi archivo routes.php:

```
  $app->get('/articulos{id}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {

      $em = getEntityManager();  
      $articulos = $em->getRepository('Articles')->findById($args['id']); 

  });
```

La estructura del proyecto es la siguiente: [Proyecto](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton)

La **petición HTTP** que realizo es un `get(id)`.

¿Alguien conoce la solución?

Comment: Cómo está definida la entidad de `Articles`? Por otro lado, cómo es que `getEntityManager` tiene visibilidad dentro del closure? Está registrada como función global?

Comment: La entidad de `Articles` está definida con cuatro atributos: id, nombre, peso y `getEntityManager` está definida como función global

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista veo un error que tendrías que arreglar o me gustaria saber si ha sido un problema del copia pega.

```
  $app->get('/articulos{id}'
```

y tendría que ser

```
  $app->get('/articulos/{id}'
```

por que eso seguro da error y puede terminar en el error que comentas